# what is this android_clip.h and hello_clip.h file format and how can i make?

Tags: android, c++, audio, android-ndk

I want to play sound with android ndk. So I am studying an example. This is an example address.

> https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-audio

I see very strange files when i study. there are "`Android_clip.h`" and "`Hello_clip.h`". What is the sound-file formats of "`Android_clip.h`" and "`Hello_clip.h`" here and how do I create them?

Here is part of contents of the file. (`hello_clip.h`)

```
"\x00\x00\xfd\xff\x01\x00\x01\x00\xf9\xff\xfb\xff\x02\x00\x05\x00"
"\x01\x00\x03\x00\x06\x00\x0a\x00\x0a\x00\x09\x00\x04\x00\x04\x00"
"\x06\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x05\x00\x08\x00\x01\x00\xfe\xff"
"\xff\xff\x03\x00\x04\x00\xfe\xff\xf9\xff\xfd\xff\x04\x00\xfe\xff"
"\x03\x00\x04\x00\x01\x00\xfb\xff\xfb\xff\xfc\xff\xfb\xff\x03\x00"
"\xfc\xff\xf9\xff\xfc\xff\x01\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\xf9\xff\xfa\xff"
"\x04\x00\x06\x00\xfe\xff\xfa\xff\xfd\xff\x01\x00\xfe\xff\xfe\xff"
"\xfe\xff\xfd\xff\xfd\xff\xfd\xff\xfe\xff\xff\xff\xfd\xff\xfa\xff"
"\xfe\xff\x00\x00\x03\x00\xfe\xff\xfc\xff\xfb\xff\xfe\xff\x01\x00"
"\x02\x00\x01\x00\xff\xff\x09\x00\x0c\x00\x10\x00\x07\x00\x07\x00"
"\x04\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\xf5\xff\xf7\xff\x02\x00\x08\x00\xfe\xff"
"\xfe\xff\x05\x00\x06\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\xfb\xff\xf9\xff\xf6\xff"
"\xf7\xff\xfd\xff\x02\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x08\x00\x07\x00\x08\x00"
"\x04\x00\xfe\xff\x02\x00\x0b\x00\x0c\x00\x05\x00\x04\x00\x03\x00"
"\xfe\xff\xfe\xff\xfb\xff\xf3\xff\xe8\xff\xee\xff\xfd\xff\x04\x00"
"\xfc\xff\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\xff\xfe\xff\xf2\xff\xf3\xff\xfa\xff"
"\x04\x00\xf7\xff\xfe\xff\x09\x00\x0d\x00\x0b\x00\x08\x00\x01\x00"
"\xff\xff\x0c\x00\x0b\x00\x07\x00\x01\x00\x05\x00\x08\x00\x0b\x00"
"\x05\x00\xfe\xff\xf6\xff\xf9\xff\xfb\xff\xfa\xff\xf8\xff\x02\x00"
"\x05\x00\x06\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x0b\x00\x02\x00\xf8\xff"
"\x01\x00\xfb\xff\xfa\xff\x06\x00\x07\x00\xfb\xff\x02\x00\x06\x00"
"\x00\x00\x01\x00\x04\x00\xf4\xff\xfa\xff\x00\x00\xf8\xff\xf6\xff"
"\x02\x00\xfd\xff\xf0\xff\xfe\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\xfc\xff\x00\x00"
"\xf6\xff\x01\x00\x08\x00\x03\x00\xfc\xff\x06\x00\x0d\x00\x01\x00"
"\x04\x00\x05\x00\x01\x00\xf7\xff\xff\xff\xfc\xff\xff\xff\x03\x00"
"\x00\x00\xfc\xff\x06\x00\x07\x00\xff\xff\xfa\xff\xfa\xff\x02\x00"
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf5\xff\xfa\xff\xff\xff\x06\x00\xfc\xff\xf9\xff"
"\xff\xff\x04\x00\x08\x00\x06\x00\x01\x00\xf7\xff\xfe\xff\xfc\xff"
"\xfe\xff\x02\x00\x07\x00\xfb\xff\xfc\xff\x08\x00\x0b\x00\x05\x00"
"\x0a\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x11\x00\x0e\x00\xfd\xff\xf1\xff"
"\xef\xff\xfe\xff\x02\x00\xf8\xff\xf2\xff\xfb\xff\xfe\xff\x0a\x00"
"\xfd\xff\xfa\xff\xf9\xff\xee\xff\xf7\xff\xff\xff\x05\x00\xfc\xff"
"\xf6\xff\xfd\xff\x0f\x00\x0a\x00\x05\x00\xf7\xff\xf5\xff\xf8\xff"
"\x09\x00\x10\x00\xff\xff\xfd\xff\xf4\xff\xff\xff\xfe\xff\xff\xff"
"\xfe\xff\xef\xff\xfa\xff\x06\x00\x17\x00\x11\x00\x13\x00\x11\x00"
"\xfe\xff\x05\x00\x0b\x00\xfe\xff\xee\xff\x07\x00\x0b\x00\xff\xff"
"\x01\x00\x0b\x00\x0a\x00\x08\x00\x0b\x00\x02\x00\xf4\xff\xfa\xff"
"\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x09\x00\xf5\xff\xf6\xff\x06\x00\xfc\xff"
"\xf0\xff\xff\xff\x05\x00\xf0\xff\x0a\x00\x23\x00\x08\x00\xfd\xff"
"\x03\x00\xf7\xff\xee\xff\x03\x00\xfc\xff\xe2\xff\xf4\xff\xfe\xff"
"\xff\xff\x10\x00\x19\x00\xf6\xff\xe7\xff\xf6\xff\xf3\xff\xe5\xff"
"\xee\xff\xea\xff\xdc\xff\xf3\xff\xf9\xff\x02\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00"
"\xe6\xff\xef\xff\x02\x00\x09\x00\x09\x00\x0b\x00\x09\x00\x00\x00"
"\x08\x00\x07\x00\x11\x00\x12\x00\x1a\x00\x17\x00\x2f\x00\x35\x00"
"\x2c\x00\x2d\x00\x20\x00\x03\x00\x02\x00\x12\x00\x0e\x00\x11\x00"
"\x21\x00\x1d\x00\x13\x00\x25\x00\x1c\x00\x05\x00\xf9\xff\xf4\xff"
"\xdd\xff\xf1\xff\x0c\x00\x15\x00\x1d\x00\x32\x00\x2a\x00\x1a\x00"
"\x1f\x00\xfe\xff\xcf\xff\xcf\xff\xeb\xff\xde\xff\xf4\xff\x03\x00"
"\x00\x00\x10\x00\x17\x00\xf0\xff\xcc\xff\xc7\xff\x8c\xff\x58\xff"
"\x5c\xff\x4e\xff\x0f\xff\xf6\xfe\xd6\xfe\xb5\xfe\xc5\xfe\xd6\xfe"
"\xe1\xfe\x08\xff\x5e\xff\x9a\xff\xe2\xff\x43\x00\x92\x00\xca\x00"
"\x10\x01\x32\x01\x42\x01\x6c\x01\x7e\x01\x72\x01\x6e\x01\x71\x01"
"\x56\x01\x53\x01\x53\x01\x30\x01\x05\x01\xfb\x00\xca\x00\x8c\x00"
"\x62\x00\x1b\x00\xbe\xff\x8e\xff\x67\xff\x40\xff\x44\xff\x61\xff"
"\x6a\xff\x80\xff\xab\xff\xb4\xff\xc6\xff\xca\xff\xb2\xff\x80\xff"
"\x79\xff\x6f\xff\x7d\xff\xa1\xff\xb5\xff\xb4\xff\xe1\xff\xfb\xff"
"\x0c\x00\x1e\x00\x30\x00\x16\x00\xfe\xff\xf4\xff\xe8\xff\xef\xff"
"\xbf\xff\x85\xff\xf1\xfe\x8a\xfe\x08\xfe\xca\xfd\x68\xfd\x26\xfd"
"\xd2\xfc\xe2\xfc\x88\xfd\xb4\xfe\x28\x00\x6c\x01\xa8\x02\x51\x03"
"\xb6\x03\x8a\x03\x0f\x03\x00\x02\x11\x01\x34\x00\xed\xff\x2d\x00"
"\x01\x01\xdc\x01\xb0\x02\x38\x03\x22\x03\xbb\x02\xf8\x01\x1e\x01"
"\xfb\xff\x1f\xff\x2d\xfe\xb0\xfd\x80\xfd\xbb\xfd\x0e\xfe\xac\xfe"
"\x3b\xff\xb0\xff\x13\x00\x58\x00\x82\x00\x81\x00\x73\x00\x01\x00"
"\xa3\xff\x2f\xff\xf6\xfe\xc5\xfe\x12\xff\x5d\xff\xee\xff\x7a\x00"
"\xff\x00\x56\x01\xa1\x01\x90\x01\x17\x01\x8f\x00\xc5\xff\xf5\xfe"
"\x20\xfe\xa3\xfd\x1a\xfd\xe4\xfc\xe0\xfc\xfe\xfc\x3c\xfd\xca\xfd"
"\x1b\xfe\xa0\xfe\x0b\xff\xbf\xff\xfc\xff\xbb\x00\x01\x01\x7d\x01"
"\xed\x01\x5c\x02\xa0\x02\xac\x02\xd3\x02\x5c\x02\x42\x02\xc1\x01"
"\xb7\x01\x4b\x01\x9e\x01\x4c\x01\x60\x01\xf1\x00\xbc\x00\xff\xff"
"\x89\xff\xf7\xfe\x72\xfe\x21\xfe\xe5\xfd\xf6\xfd\xfe\xfd\xcb\xfe"
"\x3f\xff\x10\x00\x65\x00\xec\x00\xc1\x00\xe9\x00\xa9\x00\xa0\x00"
"\x86\x00\xb3\x00\xc7\x00\xf4\x00\x27\x01\x42\x01\x41\x01\x22\x01"
"\xfb\x00\xac\x00\x7a\x00\x49\x00\x19\x00\xf6\xff\xd6\xff\x82\xff"
"\x20\xff\xdc\xfe\x7d\xfe\xec\xfd\x8f\xfd\x31\xfd\x05\xfd\x8c\xfc"
"\x7a\xfc\xcb\xfb\x94\xfb\x71\xfb\xe9\xfb\xb7\xfc\x67\xfe\x20\x00"
"\xd7\x01\x78\x03\x76\x04\xb6\x04\x40\x04\x97\x03\x32\x02\x2c\x01"
"\x57\x00\x49\x00\x87\x00\xb4\x01\xa1\x02\x84\x03\xea\x03\xe3\x03"
"\x11\x03\x15\x02\xc9\x00\x49\xff\xfd\xfd\xde\xfc\x50\xfc\x49\xfc"
"\x22\xfd\x0a\xfe\x55\xff\x29\x00\xb0\x00\x9b\x00\xa6\x00\x5a\x00"
"\x51\x00\x30\x00\x18\x00\xe5\xff\xdc\xff\xe5\xff\x29\x00\xa3\x00"
"\x27\x01\xaa\x01\xfa\x01\xec\x01\xa2\x01\x39\x01\xb5\x00\x3a\x00"
"\xc2\xff\x35\xff\x9f\xfe\x6e\xfe\x27\xfe\x54\xfe\x7b\xfe\x0e\xff"
"\x29\xff\x62\xff\x4d\xff\xc7\xff\x29\xff\xe1\xff\xb6\xff\x6d\x00"
"\xe0\xff\xd8\x00\x1a\x00\x92\x00\xce\xfe\x16\xfe\x8c\xfb\x76\xf5"
"\x4e\xf5\xf5\xf3\x3a\xf8\x59\xfc\x7e\x04\xd5\x07\x35\x0d\x3e\x0e"
"\x34\x0d\xcf\x09\xe1\x04\xe2\xfe\x5e\xf9\xb5\xf6\x01\xf5\x0f\xf8"
"\x37\xfb\x42\x01\x82\x05\x2a\x0b\x35\x0d\xcb\x0e\x1b\x0c\x3c\x08"
"\x47\x01\x1c\xfb\x82\xf5\x95\xf2\xab\xf2\x76\xf5\x3c\xfa\x42\xff"
"\x72\x04\xd0\x07\x77\x0a\xb7\x0a\x00\x0a\x88\x06\x30\x02\x0d\xfc"
"\x7a\xf6\xef\xf1\x1d\xf1\xad\xf2\xb5\xf7\x05\xfe\x5c\x04\xed\x08"
"\x41\x0b\xe1\x0a\x16\x08\x89\x04\x10\x00\x2b\xfc\x78\xf9\x94\xf8"
"\x18\xf9\xa9\xfb\x51\xfe\x6d\x01\x74\x03\x95\x04\x83\x04\xd8\x03"
"\x70\x02\x75\x01\x98\x00\xe5\xff\x52\xff\xee\xfe\x27\xfe\x2e\xfe"
"\x21\xfe\x80\xfe\xef\xff\xbf\x00\xea\x00\x2b\x01\xf6\xff\x99\xfd"
"\xd9\xfc\x1c\xfb\xc9\xf9\xb5\xf8\xb9\xf9\x1b\xf8\xf1\xfa\x93\xfd"
"\xf1\x00\xdf\x04\xc5\x07\xaf\x08\x27\x08\xb0\x07\xbf\x04\x9c\x03"
"\x48\x01\xfa\xff\x48\xfe\x8c\xfe\x4d\xfe\x46\x00\x2a\x02\x76\x04"
"\xf0\x05\x0b\x07\x82\x06\x3f\x05\x56\x03\x85\x00\xb2\xfd\xb0\xfa"
"\x90\xf8\x06\xf7\x71\xf7\xc5\xf8\xda\xfb\xea\xfe\x36\x02\x40\x04"
"\xbd\x04\x9c\x03\x88\x01\xb2\xfe\x03\xfc\x27\xfa\x8c\xf9\xaf\xf9"
"\xaf\xfb\xde\xfd\x7a\x00\x01\x03\xcf\x04\xa4\x05\xcd\x05\xfd\x04"
"\x7f\x03\x2b\x02\xb3\x00\x8f\xff\x29\xff\xdd\xfe\x91\xfe\xd1\xfe"
"\xc4\xfe\x0e\xff\xcd\xff\x94\x00\xdd\x00\x9e\x01\xb5\x01\xbc\x01"
"\x82\x01\x62\x01\x5a\x00\x44\x00\x39\x00\x00\x00\x95\x00\x74\xff"
"\x9f\xfd\x1c\xfb\x77\xf7\xc7\xf4\x18\xf3\xf3\xf3\x37\xf7\x8f\xfc"
"\x4c\x03\x54\x09\x4a\x0e\x10\x10\x74\x0f\x65\x0b\x13\x06\xe6\xff"
"\x85\xfa\x9e\xf6\x44\xf5\xea\xf5\xcd\xf8\x5d\xfd\x67\x02\xd1\x07"
"\xe7\x0b\x63\x0e\x35\x0e\xb0\x0b\x99\x06\xa4\x00\x6c\xfa\x6c\xf5"
"\x39\xf2\x78\xf1\xcb\xf2\x2c\xf6\xc8\xfa\x10\x00\x4d\x05\x44\x09"
"\xcb\x0b\x89\x0b\xf6\x08\x34\x04\xa3\xfe\x95\xf8\x44\xf4\x03\xf2"
"\xc6\xf2\x3e\xf6\xcf\xfb\xe2\x01\x9b\x07\x56\x0b\xc5\x0c\xd9\x0b"
"\xb3\x08\xd2\x04\x9d\x00\xc2\xfd\x75\xfb\x53\xfb\x26\xfb\xa8\xfc"
"\x60\xfd\x7e\xff\x0a\x00\x15\x02\x18\x02\x2c\x04\xae\x03\xa3\x04"
"\xdd\x03\x79\x03\xe7\x02\x16\x02\xe4\x00\x5b\xfa\x81\xf6\xee\xed"
"\x55\xec\x7b\xe9\xb9\xee\x75\xf3\x4b\xfe\x09\x07\x51\x10\xee\x15"
"\x6b\x17\xf3\x14\x31\x0e\xdb\x06\x06\xfe\x1b\xf9\xeb\xf3\x15\xf3"
"\xad\xf1\xcf\xf4\x85\xf7\x8d\xfe\x4e\x04\xd2\x0b\xc8\x0f\xb9\x12"
"\xe9\x10\x08\x0d\x2c\x06\xbe\xfe\xa1\xf7\x30\xf2\x3e\xef\xc7\xee"
"\x5f\xf1\x5f\xf5\x6a\xfb\x14\x01\x4e\x07\x53\x0b\xbf\x0e\x91\x0e"
"\x65\x0d\x91\x08\x8a\x03\xb1\xfc\x6b\xf7\xcb\xf2\xe7\xf0\x70\xf1"
"\x42\xf4\x05\xf9\x74\xfe\x43\x04\x93\x08\xdf\x0b\xb1\x0c\x47\x0c"
"\x3c\x09\xac\x05\x88\x00\x2f\xfc\x7e\xf8\xdf\xf6\xb7\xf6\x1b\xf9"
"\x3b\xfc\x81\x00\xd5\x03\x88\x06\x2c\x07\x31\x07\xe3\x05\x08\x04"
"\x9c\x02\x3c\x01\x38\x01\x63\xff\x95\xff\x88\xf8\x92\xf5\x15\xf0"
"\xac\xed\xd6\xed\x0c\xf1\x8e\xf5\x16\xfc\x34\x04\x7c\x09\xd3\x0f"
"\x26\x11\xf4\x10\x3a\x0d\x97\x09\xa7\x03\xda\x00\x90\xfd\xed\xfb"
"\xbb\xfa\x8b\xfa\x0a\xfa\xab\xfb\x4e\xfd\xdd\xff\x10\x03\xca\x05"
"\xd7\x07\x8c\x08\xf2\x07\x94\x05\x18\x03\x85\xff\x95\xfc\x1d\xfa"
"\xec\xf8\xa6\xf8\x37\xfa\xd7\xfb\x3c\xfe\x40\x00\x0a\x02\xa0\x02"
"\x18\x03\xdc\x01\x04\x01\xc1\xff\xb4\xfe\x5b\xfe\x5e\xfe\x53\xfe"
"\xc1\xfe\xc8\xfe\xd2\xfe\xf2\xfe\x63\xff\xd8\xff\xe5\x00\x07\x02"
"\xd3\x02\xa8\x03\xe4\x03\x43\x03\x40\x02\xac\x00\xea\xfe\xc1\xfd"
"\x24\xfd\x50\xfd\xc2\xfd\xe4\xfe\x48\xff\x5c\x00\x61\x00\x1c\x01"
"\xf9\x00\x41\x02\x5d\x02\xcf\x03\x4a\x03\x22\x04\xd5\xff\x6f\xfc"
"\xef\xf8\xbd\xf3\x17\xf3\xb0\xf1\x4e\xf3\x59\xf5\xbb\xfb\x9b\xff"
"\x34\x06\xf1\x09\x15\x0c\x50\x0c\xbe\x0b\x33\x09\x98\x07\x1e\x06"
"\xa0\x03\x45\x02\x4a\x00\x3d\xfe\xb8\xfc\x5b\xfc\x73\xfb\xb3\xfc"
"\x76\xfd\x05\xff\x30\x00\xc0\x01\xc4\x01\x85\x02\xee\x01\x6f\x01"
"\xd6\x00\x27\x00\x67\xff\x83\xff\x59\xff\x59\xff\x7d\xff\xb6\xfe"
"\xaa\xfd\xed\xfc\x0f\xfc\x8e\xfb\x75\xfc\x3c\xfd\x51\xff\x5b\x01"
"\x23\x03\xf9\x03\x4e\x04\x61\x03\x36\x02\xd5\x00\x85\xff\xb6\xfe"
"\xfb\xfe\x36\xff\x2d\x00\x2f\x01\x70\x01\x38\x01\xc1\x00\x3b\xff"
"\xc2\xfe\x44\xfe\x26\xfe\xb0\xfe\xb2\xff\x10\x00\x01\x01\x54\x01"
"\xae\x01\xfd\x01\x52\x02\x92\x02\x12\x00\x75\xff\xa0\xfb\xcf\xf9"
"\x69\xf7\x49\xf6\x3a\xf5\xae\xf6\x12\xf9\x4b\xfc\x10\x01\x2f\x04"
"\x17\x07\x55\x08\x3b\x09\x7e\x08\xab\x08\x54\x07\x68\x06\x0a\x05"
"\xf6\x03\x81\x02\xa3\x01\x4c\x00\x0a\xff\xbc\xfd\x95\xfc\xd4\xfb"
"\x7a\xfb\xb0\xfb\x12\xfc\xef\xfc\xcd\xfd\xdc\xfe\xce\xff\xbd\x00"
"\x80\x01\x5d\x02\xec\x02\x20\x03\x02\x03\x30\x02\xee\x00\xb3\xff"
"\xdf\xfd\x78\xfc\x6c\xfb\x25\xfb\xd8\xfb\x6d\xfd\x78\xff\x7e\x01"
"\x4f\x03\x5e\x04\x6d\x04\xd5\x03\x70\x02\x45\x01\x24\x00\x2e\x00"
"\xc4\xff\xe5\xff\x04\x00\x72\xff\x3f\xff\x69\xfe\xe4\xfd\x66\xfd"
"\xe2\xfd\x36\xfe\xf0\xff\xe1\x00\x3e\x02\xe6\x02\x82\x00\xd0\xfe"
"\xc0\xfb\x30\xf9\xf5\xf7\x84\xf7\x4c\xf7\x19\xf9\xaf\xfb\x27\xfe"
"\xeb\x01\x57\x04\xc9\x05\x11\x07\x5f\x07\x1c\x07\x9e\x07\x4c\x07"
"\xc0\x06\x27\x06\xae\x04\xff\x02\x9f\x01\xdd\xff\x8f\xfe\xbd\xfd"
"\xfa\xfc\xce\xfc\xed\xfc\xf9\xfc\x47\xfd\x90\xfd\x94\xfd\x9d\xfd"
"\xa6\xfd\x93\xfd\x02\xfe\xae\xfe\xa1\xff\x18\x01\x75\x02\x67\x03"
"\xf5\x03\x88\x03\x4f\x02\x01\x01\x64\xff\x2b\xfe\xac\xfd\x85\xfd"
"\x0a\xfe\xde\xfe\x7b\xff\x2f\x00\xa1\x00\xe8\x00\x0a\x01\x58\x01"
"\x5f\x01\xb8\x01\x85\x01\x78\x01\x85\x00\x3e\x00\x50\xff\x95\xfe"
"\xcc\xfe\x90\xfe\x0b\x00\x64\x00\x52\x01\x5b\x01\x09\x01\xd4\x00"
"\x1f\x00\xd0\x00\x5b\x00\x96\x01\x3e\x00\x47\xfe\x69\xfc\xff\xf8"
"\x48\xf7\x7a\xf5\x2e\xf5\x7d\xf5\x8b\xf8\x28\xfb\x39\xff\xc4\x02"
"\x08\x05\xb3\x06\x95\x07\x9f\x07\xa2\x07\x3d\x08\xee\x07\x26\x08"
"\xd8\x07\xb6\x06\x67\x05\x00\x04\xad\x01\x07\x00\x54\xfe\x05\xfd"
"\x1a\xfc\xe5\xfb\x40\xfb\x90\xfb\xe5\xfb\x18\xfc\xc1\xfc\x58\xfd"
"\xb5\xfd\x98\xfe\x54\xff\x1f\x00\x35\x01\xeb\x01\x2c\x02\x2a\x02"
"\xcd\x01\x95\x00\xce\xff\x96\xfe\xaa\xfd\x98\xfd\xf6\xfd\xa4\xfe"
"\xd8\xff\xb3\x00\x37\x01\xad\x01\xce\x01\xc1\x01\x0f\x02\x34\x02"
"\x39\x02\x6f\x02\x48\x02\xf3\x01\x48\x01\x53\x00\x90\xff\xb5\xfe"
"\xdc\xfe\xb1\xfe\x8a\xff\xbc\xff\x6d\x00\x48\x00\x79\x00\xf5\xff"
"\x7e\xff\x4d\xfe\x9b\xfb\xd4\xfa\xf5\xf7\x2d\xf7\x38\xf6\x68\xf6"
"\x12\xf7\xa9\xf9\xfd\xfb\x26\xff\x77\x02\x9a\x04\xb5\x06\xf5\x07"
"\x95\x08\xc9\x08\x62\x09\xd3\x08\xbc\x08\xe1\x07\xa3\x06\x16\x05"
"\xbe\x03\xcf\x01\x81\x00\x0f\xff\xbb\xfd\x9f\xfc\xe8\xfb\x0e\xfb"
"\xd4\xfa\xe1\xfa\x07\xfb\x9d\xfb\x5c\xfc\x16\xfd\x19\xfe\x53\xff"
"\x52\x00\x62\x01\x1f\x02\x36\x02\x06\x02\xe2\x01\x05\x01\xbf\x00"
"\x05\x00\x8b\xff\x45\xff\x48\xff\x3d\xff\x98\xff\xe1\xff\x07\x00"
"\x6b\x00\xd4\x00\x2a\x01\xbe\x01\x1a\x02\x2a\x02\x3d\x02\xf2\x01"
"\x62\x01\xe4\x00\x6a\x00\xb6\xff\x06\x00\x65\xff\xb6\xff\x81\xff"
"\x56\xff\x40\xff\x42\xff\x16\xff\xc4\xfe\xdc\xfd\x06\xfc\xf8\xfa"
"\xdd\xf8\xe0\xf7\x59\xf7\x79\xf7\x53\xf8\x79\xfa\xb0\xfc\x62\xff"
"\x27\x02\xf9\x03\x88\x05\xbe\x06\x3f\x07\xe9\x07\xa1\x08\x92\x08"
"\x74\x08\xde\x07\x9f\x06\x6b\x05\x3d\x04\x85\x02\x49\x01\xc0\xff"
"\x16\xfe\xc9\xfc\xbc\xfb\xb9\xfa\x8b\xfa\xb9\xfa\xd1\xfa\xb0\xfb"
"\x7d\xfc\x1c\xfd\x5d\xfe\x6b\xff\x2e\x00\x33\x01\xb7\x01\x86\x01"
"\x8c\x01\x2e\x01\x6f\x00\x61\x00\x01\x00\xd1\xff\x53\x00\xb8\x00"
"\x29\x01\xb8\x01\xd2\x01\x80\x01\x73\x01\xf4\x00\xc3\x00\xcb\x00"
"\xde\x00\xbe\x00\xbc\x00\x36\x00\xba\xff\x6d\xff\xce\xfe\xc6\xfe"
"\xde\xfe\x59\xff\x08\x00\x46\x00\x7e\x00\x29\xff\x76\xfd\xbc\xfb"
"\x37\xf9\x54\xf8\xa1\xf7\xe5\xf7\x62\xf8\x07\xfa\x66\xfb\x8e\xfd"
"\xe8\xff\xaa\x01\xd6\x03\xac\x05\xeb\x06\x1f\x08\x2f\x09\x1d\x09"
"\x21\x09\x5f\x08\x17\x07\xc3\x05\x99\x04\x01\x03\xfb\x01\xb9\x00"
"\x40\xff\xed\xfd\xc4\xfc\x6a\xfb\xbd\xfa\x4c\xfa\x14\xfa\x66\xfa"
"\x08\xfb\xba\xfb\xe7\xfc\x55\xfe\x7b\xff\x08\x01\x39\x02\xe5\x02"
"\x7a\x03\xa8\x03\xa1\x02\x09\x02\x37\x01\x26\x00\xdb\xff\x9e\xff"
"\x5b\xff\x50\xff\x73\xff\x04\xff\x59\xff\x84\xff\x7d\xff\x18\x00"
"\x8f\x00\x9f\x00\x2b\x01\x3a\x01\xb0\x00\xea\x00\x82\x00\x76\x00"
"\x75\x00\x62\x01\xce\x00\x41\x02\x6f\x01\xbc\x01\x45\x01\x18\x01"
"\xbd\x00\x99\x00\x3b\x00\xac\xfc\xb1\xfc\x1a\xf8\xa1\xf6\x15\xf4"
"\x11\xf4\xbd\xf3\x32\xf6\x76\xf8\x0a\xfb\x35\xff\x1d\x01\xe3\x03"
"\xcf\x05\xc2\x07\x5a\x08\x70\x0a\x91\x0a\x47\x0b\x22\x0b\x86\x0a"
"\xb1\x08\xae\x07\x39\x05\x6c\x03\xb3\x01\xfd\xff\x24\xfe\x02\xfd"
"\x7d\xfb\x2e\xfa\xbe\xf9\xfa\xf8\x15\xf9\xa6\xf9\x85\xfa\x82\xfb"
"\x5d\xfd\x7e\xfe\x20\x00\x95\x01\x79\x02\xf8\x02\x81\x03\x94\x02"
"\x92\x01\x81\x00\x17\xff\x34\xfe\xf8\xfd\xc3\xfd\x3e\xfe\x0d\xff"
"\x19\xff\x76\xff\x4a\x00\xcf\x00\x7a\x01\x13\x02\x91\x02\xe4\x02"
"\x2d\x03\x76\x02\x36\x02\x67\x01\x1a\x01\xa7\x00\x58\x01\x26\x01"
"\x91\x01\xd6\x01\x8c\x01\xf8\x00\x1c\x00\xd1\xff\x99\xff\xd3\xff"
"\xed\xfb\x4d\xfa\x9e\xf7\x94\xf5\x8b\xf3\x58\xf3\x42\xf3\x35\xf6"
"\x86\xf9\x37\xfc\x40\x00\x35\x03\x22\x05\x9e\x06\x5a\x08\x82\x08"
"\x7c\x0a\xd8\x0a\xc4\x0a\x43\x0a\xad\x09\xa2\x07\x8e\x06\xa4\x04"
"\xc8\x02\x57\x01\xf3\xff\x2c\xfe\x2f\xfd\xeb\xfb\x75\xfa\x09\xfa"
"\xa6\xf9\x8d\xf9\x55\xfa\x56\xfb\x44\xfc\xea\xfd\x00\xff\x1a\x00"
"\x86\x01\x45\x02\x7e\x02\xca\x02\x18\x01\xef\xff\x86\xfe\x57\xfd"
"\xde\xfc\x6a\xfd\xf7\xfd\x8a\xff\x25\x01\x74\x01\x1a\x02\x0b\x03"
"\x10\x03\x3d\x03\x18\x03\xb5\x02\x8d\x02\x6d\x02\x44\x01\xcc\x00"
"\xb8\x00\x9c\xff\xf9\xff\xee\xff\x82\x00\xd6\x00\x37\x01\x6a\x00"
"\x05\x00\xa7\xff\x41\xfe\x56\xfb\x33\xf8\xfa\xf5\x71\xf4\xfe\xf3"
"\x7b\xf3\xe9\xf4\xdf\xf7\x43\xfc\x13\x00\xd9\x03\xe7\x06\xa0\x08"
"\xce\x09\x62\x0a\xa1\x0a\x98\x0a\x24\x0a\xca\x08\x2a\x07\x3c\x05"
"\x52\x03\xb6\x01\x95\x00\x23\xff\x09\xfe\x27\xfd\x55\xfc\x82\xfb"
"\x4b\xfb\x16\xfb\x62\xfb\x1c\xfc\x8b\xfc\x43\xfd\x2b\xfe\x0b\xff"
"\xdc\xff\x10\x01\xa3\x01\x74\x02\x90\x02\x47\x02\xfb\x00\x71\xff"
"\x5c\xfd\x91\xfc\xdc\xfb\x34\xfd\xba\xfc\x4e\xff\x7c\x03\x04\x04"
"\x96\x06\x97\x04\x4c\x05\xb0\x04\xb6\x03\x5d\x01\xc3\x00\x1b\xff"
"\xde\xfe\x59\xfe\x16\xfe\xc2\xfe\x6b\xff\x92\xff\x55\x00\xd0\x01"
"\xd6\x01\x22\x03\x2c\x01\xc5\x00\x7a\xf9\x7c\xf7\x3c\xf1\x2e\xf0"
"\xb3\xef\x2b\xf1\x74\xf4\x8c\xf9\xc3\xff\xd8\x04\x7b\x0b\x63\x0d"
"\x80\x0f\x11\x0e\xa8\x0c\x01\x09\xed\x07\xe9\x03\x9f\x01\x8a\xfe"
"\x9a\xfc\x67\xfb\x21\xfd\x32\xfe\x22\x01\x39\x03\x27\x04\x59\x04"
"\xc4\x03\x6a\x02\xc1\x00\xa8\xff\xc2\xfd\x99\xfc\xfb\xfa\x63\xf9"
"\x55\xf8\xcd\xf8\x4a\xf9\xe1\xfb\x76\xfe\x23\x01\x01\x03\xbc\x03"
"\x65\x02\xf2\x01\xb6\x00\x2b\x00\xcc\x00\x1f\x01\x59\x01\x7c\x02"
"\x2e\x02\x97\x02\x49\x02\xe5\x01\x0c\x01\x83\x01\xff\x00\xcd\x01"
"\x80\x01\xfd\x01\x65\x01\xa1\x01\xd4\x00\x17\x01\x68\x00\x8e\x00"
"\x12\x00\x42\x00\x70\x00\xf2\xff\xe8\xfe\x27\xf5\x29\xf3\x24\xeb"
"\x8c\xeb\xb9\xec\xb8\xf2\x25\xf8\x0d\x01\x64\x07\xfe\x0c\xf4\x12"
"\xa9\x12\xde\x11\xf8\x0c\x7b\x07\x10\x00\x5e\xfd\xc7\xf7\xe0\xf6"
"\xda\xf5\xa6\xf7\x5b\xfb\xb1\x02\x3c\x08\xbb\x0e\xbe\x11\xa8\x11"
"\xef\x0e\xc4\x09\xb5\x02\x38\xfc\x87\xf6\x21\xf1\xc0\xee\x68\xed"
"\xcf\xee\x28\xf3\xef\xf9\x56\x01\x89\x09\xe6\x0e\xd9\x11\x03\x11"
"\xfb\x0c\x84\x05\xa5\xfd\x53\xf5\x98\xef\xf5\xec\xc3\xed\xe9\xf1"
"\x78\xf8\x03\x00\x86\x07\xa3\x0d\x3b\x11\xce\x11\x28\x0f\x57\x0a"
"\x61\x04\xf8\xfe\xe2\xfa\x80\xf8\xc8\xf7\xfd\xf7\x2a\xfa\x9e\xfd"
"\x03\x01\xc3\x04\xf7\x07\xbf\x08\xb8\x08\x49\x08\xf2\x06\x2c\xff"
"\x4b\xf4\x35\xec\x81\xe5\x5d\xe4\xdf\xe7\x3c\xee\xbd\xf6\xd2\x00"
"\xa6\x09\xcc\x11\x11\x17\x51\x17\xdc\x13\x20\x0d\x29\x04\xcc\xfc"
"\x69\xf7\x3f\xf3\xce\xf1\x2a\xf3\x8c\xf7\x19\xff\x40\x08\x84\x10"
"\x1f\x16\x4b\x17\x67\x14\x0c\x0e\xba\x05\x70\xfd\x9d\xf6\xb2\xf1"
"\x84\xee\x59\xed\xcd\xee\x7d\xf2\xd6\xf8\x29\x00\xe7\x07\xb3\x0d"
"\x74\x10\xa1\x0e\xc9\x09\x74\x02\xfa\xfa\x69\xf5\x11\xf2\xe9\xf1"
"\x4e\xf4\x29\xf8\xdb\xfc\x28\x02\x3e\x06\x32\x0a\xa5\x0b\x05\x0c"
"\xce\x09\x7b\x07\x02\x03\xb4\xff\x96\xfb\x57\xfa\x26\xf9\x7c\xfa"
"\x39\xfb\x27\xfd\x27\xff\xce\x02\xf4\x04\xdc\x08\x60\x07\x58\xfc"
"\x16\xf9\xaa\xed\xcb\xec\xcc\xec\x29\xf3\xf5\xf7\x1a\x01\x6d\x05"
"\x1b\x0b\xb5\x0e\xbf\x0e\x3b\x0e\xd8\x09\xe4\x06\x39\xfe\x91\xfc"
"\x9b\xf5\x24\xf6\x05\xf5\xad\xf9\xba\xfd\x50\x05\x7d\x0a\xa0\x0f"
"\xc6\x10\x92\x0f\xfc\x0b\xbc\x05\x82\xff\x9c\xf8\x5e\xf4\xe4\xef"
"\x12\xf0\x49\xf0\xae\xf5\xf4\xfa\xd5\x03\xa7\x0a\x36\x11\x62\x12"
"\xf3\x11\x4f\x0b\xb7\x04\xe3\xf9\x88\xf1\x85\xeb\x7f\xe9\x88\xed"
"\x90\xf3\x3f\xfd\x6e\x04\x82\x0c\xe9\x0f\x27\x12\x4d\x0f\xba\x0b"
"\x11\x03\x89\xfd\x65\xf6\x6e\xf5\xa7\xf4\x36\xf9\x9c\xfb\x1e\x01"
"\x5e\x02\x8b\x05\x82\x06\xca\x09\x61\x0b\x50\x0c\xfb\x09\x08\x08"
"\x32\x07\x2e\xee\x76\xeb\x66\xdc\xef\xdc\x5e\xdd\x84\xea\x21\xf3"
"\x2c\x02\xb2\x0f\xfa\x19\xf8\x21\x2c\x20\x77\x1d\x5a\x0f\xd9\x03"
"\xb5\xf4\xe1\xef\x25\xe7\xe6\xea\x7e\xeb\x51\xf5\x3f\xfe\x63\x0c"
"\xd6\x15\x88\x1f\x22\x1f\x1a\x1c\x36\x12\x05\x06\xdb\xf9\x2d\xef"
"\xa6\xe8\x0f\xe4\x33\xe5\x22\xe8\x03\xf2\xa7\xfb\xb9\x09\x2b\x14"
"\xb4\x1c\xa6\x1d\xc8\x1a\xec\x0e\x1e\x03\xe3\xf3\x11\xe8\xb6\xe0"
"\x87\xdf\x38\xe4\xe6\xed\x7a\xfa\xfd\x05\x97\x10\x1c\x18\x58\x1a"
"\x1e\x18\xc7\x11\xef\x06\x48\xfc\xad\xf2\x69\xee\xf7\xee\x31\xf3"
"\x77\xf9\x5b\x00\xab\x04\x0b\x09\xb0\x0b\x3b\x0f\xf0\x0f\xe6\x0f"
"\x16\x0b\xef\x04\x0e\xfe\xe4\xf9\x99\xf2\xbb\xe3\x6d\xe2\x11\xde"
"\xa6\xe1\xeb\xe8\x53\xf6\x51\x01\xbc\x0e\x47\x19\xcd\x1e\xb8\x1f"
"\xe0\x19\x59\x11\xc6\x02\x8e\xf7\x26\xed\xbc\xe9\x8d\xe7\x26\xed"
"\x7a\xf3\x70\xff\x57\x0b\xd4\x18\xf3\x1f\xf5\x22\x82\x1d\x0f\x14"
"\x28\x06\x7a\xf9\x41\xee\x69\xe7\xb0\xe4\xc4\xe4\x1c\xea\xe5\xf1"
"\x29\xfd\x7c\x08\x9d\x14\x59\x1a\xcf\x1c\xd6\x16\x8c\x0e\x43\xfd"
"\x59\xf1\xd8\xe4\x54\xe0\xc1\xe1\x4c\xea\x8a\xf5\x6d\x02\x82\x0d"
"\x6d\x15\x48\x18\xbf\x16\x82\x10\xcd\x07\x01\xff\xaa\xf7\x28\xf4"
"\xba\xf2\x56\xf6\x02\xf9\x63\xfe\xe2\xff\x10\x05\xb4\x05\x7e\x0c"
"\x1f\x0c\x8d\x10\x6e\x09\x6b\x0d\x84\xf8\xe4\xe9\x78\xe1\xb8\xd9"
"\xd1\xde\xa9\xe5\x4b\xf8\xfa\xfd\xbe\x0f\xdd\x14\xad\x1e\xc2\x1a"
"\xaa\x1d\xf9\x10\xa8\x06\xdd\xf8\x75\xf0\xb0\xe8\xaf\xe8\x37\xed"
"\xd9\xf3\xe5\x00\x24\x0b\xa9\x16\x4b\x1a\x16\x1d\x27\x16\xee\x10"
"\xf7\x03\x67\xfc\xc9\xef\x34\xeb\x3b\xe5\x90\xe6\x42\xe9\xdb\xf2"
"\x96\xfc\x6e\x09\x94\x14\x54\x1b\x2d\x1d\xca\x18\x2d\x0f\x86\x01"
"\xf9\xf5\xd5\xe8\xd6\xe3\xac\xe0\xa5\xe5\x0b\xef\xdf\xfb\xad\x08"
"\x1a\x12\x94\x18\x79\x19\x90\x15\xe1\x0e\xb8\x04\x94\xfa\x9f\xf2"
"\x22\xef\x8b\xee\x4a\xf3\x1d\xf8\x32\xff\x7d\x02\x3c\x08\x1a\x0a"
"\x6b\x0e\xe3\x0e\x74\x0f\x94\x0b\xdf\x06\xba\xfe\x76\xfc\x3f\xf1"
"\x16\xe2\x54\xe2\x9a\xdd\x25\xe4\xe6\xe9\x12\xfc\xc8\x03\x4d\x13"
"\x27\x1c\x40\x21\xac\x1d\x4f\x19\x0e\x0e\x72\xfe\xbb\xf4\x9e\xeb"
"\x25\xe9\xc3\xe7\xe9\xee\x3c\xf4\xe8\x01\x57\x0c\x0d\x1a\x03\x1f"
"\xcb\x21\xe5\x1a\x83\x11\x62\x02\x9f\xf6\x45\xeb\x72\xe5\x25\xe4"
"\xa0\xe5\xb6\xeb\x07\xf4\x15\x00\x06\x0b\x2e\x17\xd3\x1c\xbd\x1e"
"\x1e\x19\xad\x0c\xae\xfa\x02\xed\x8a\xe1\x2e\xdf\xa5\xe2\x9b\xee"
"\x7e\xf9\xdf\x06\x5c\x0f\x35\x15\x87\x15\x8a\x14\xcd\x0d\x19\x07"
"\x8a\xfe\x1b\xf8\x6f\xf3\x7e\xf2\x13\xf5\x88\xf8\x20\xfe\x2c\x01"
"\x81\x05\x69\x06\x6a\x0b\x10\x0b\x59\x0f\xa8\x0a\xba\x0e\x8f\xf4"
"\xa9\xeb\x26\xde\xe4\xdb\x95\xde\x47\xeb\x10\xfd\x3a\x02\xe3\x11"
"\xcc\x13\x8a\x1b\x81\x15\x0a\x1b\xc2\x0b\x57\x05\x7d\xf6\xc8\xf1"
"\x15\xe8\x09\xeb\x40\xef\x2c\xf8\x8b\x03\x47\x0d\x89\x16\x94\x17"
"\xd7\x19\xbb\x12\x1d\x0f\x6c\x03\x48\xfe\xbc\xf1\x9e\xed\x72\xe5"
"\xb0\xe7\xfe\xe8\x3e\xf4\x7d\xfe\x76\x0b\x03\x15\xd6\x19\xbb\x19"
"\x8c\x14\x50\x0c\x73\x00\x7c\xf5\xde\xe9\x0c\xe4\x3e\xe1\x0c\xe9"
"\x00\xf2\x88\x00\x17\x0b\x40\x14\x66\x17\xd4\x16\x5f\x11\xa1\x0a"
"\x51\x00\x65\xf8\xfe\xf2\x99\xf1\xd5\xf2\xd7\xf7\xff\xfb\x54\x00"
"\x52\x03\xbc\x07\xfa\x09\xb7\x0d\xd0\x0d\xd5\x0b\xf9\x06\xf8\x05"
"\x96\xf8\xcd\xe6\x18\xe5\xa6\xdd\x61\xe3\x01\xe8\x87\xfa\x9c\xff"
"\x18\x0d\xdc\x15\x02\x1c\x67\x1a\x57\x18\x7d\x10\x9b\x00\x0c\xf8"
"\x7b\xee\xa5\xed\xce\xea\x12\xf4\x3c\xf7\xe2\x01\x5c\x08\xb7\x13"
"\xa4\x16\x20\x1a\xa2\x16\xba\x0f\x25\x05\x41\xfb\xe8\xf1\x8f\xea"
"\x97\xe9\xeb\xe8\xb2\xee\x1a\xf3\x0a\xfe\x13\x05\x73\x10\x5e\x15"
"\x5a\x1a\x5a\x16\xc8\x10\x53\x01\xf8\xf2\x49\xe7\x7e\xe1\xb1\xe4"
"\xe0\xec\xd6\xfb\x3b\x05\x77\x10\x20\x13\x5d\x16\x3d\x11\xce\x0d"
"\x63\x05\x75\xff\x92\xf7\xf9\xf4\x97\xf2\x3e\xf5\x1a\xf8\x39\xfc"
"\xe5\xff\x3e\x03\x2f\x06\x52\x08\x67\x0b\x19\x0d\xfe\x0a\x4e\xf8"
"\xcf\xf3\x37\xe4\x02\xe4\x6e\xe0\x29\xef\x9e\xf6\x8c\x04\x66\x11"
"\xf7\x17\x3e\x1c\x79\x18\x3d\x17\x9b\x07\x7a\x01\xe8\xf3\xf2\xf0"
"\x72\xe7\x65\xec\xfc\xee\x16\xfa\xdd\x03\x72\x10\x6f\x17\xc1\x18"
"\x3f\x17\xf2\x0e\xa3\x07\xe9\xfd\x6b\xf9\xf1\xf0\x6c\xef\x5b\xeb"
"\xf8\xec\x86\xee\x76\xf7\x9c\x00\xf9\x0a\xea\x13\xc7\x18\xdd\x18"
"\x44\x12\x00\x0a\x56\xfd\x98\xf2\x5f\xe8\xd2\xe4\x9f\xe6\x56\xee"
"\x40\xf9\x10\x05\x8c\x0e\xfa\x13\x76\x16\x3c\x13\x41\x0e\x6a\x05"
"\x91\xfe\xc4\xf6\x12\xf4\xe7\xf2\xed\xf5\x3c\xf8\x35\xfb\x8b\xfe"
"\x4f\x00\xfb\x03\x8f\x06\x7f\x0c\x4c\x0a\x03\x11\x6b\x02\x1a\xf7"
"\x16\xeb\xea\xe5\x41\xe3\x2c\xe6\xd5\xf4\x58\xf9\x5e\x06\xde\x0c"
"\xad\x18\xfb\x17\x48\x1d\x0e\x16\xec\x0c\x61\xff\x3f\xf5\xef\xec"
"\x8b\xe7\x98\xeb\xd4\xef\x5a\xfb\xbe\x03\x1f\x10\xba\x13\x72\x17"
"\x22\x14\xd4\x10\xed\x08\x30\x02\xfa\xf9\x08\xf2\x16\xec\x4b\xe8"
"\xb7\xe9\x33\xee\x8b\xf8\x6b\x02\x34\x0e\x50\x15\x06\x1a\x03\x18"
```

Comment: Well, in the `.c` file they've got `SLDataFormat_PCM format_pcm = {SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM, 1, SL_SAMPLINGRATE_8,
        SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16, SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
        SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER, SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN};`, so I'd say 8kHz mono uncompressed PCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create them using bin2c tool as written here: https://googlesamples.github.io/android-audio-high-performance/guides/opensl_es.html

> Compiled and linked inline
>
> You can link your audio content directly into the shared library, and then play it using an audio player with buffer queue data locator.  This is most suitable for short PCM format clips.  The example code uses this technique for the "Hello" and "Android" clips. The PCM data was converted to hex strings using a bin2c tool (not supplied).